# Failed to build multiple assemblies in maven. No assemby descriptor found

Tags: maven

I'm having some trouble when trying to generate two or more jars from a maven project when using the assembly plugin.

I have the following maven pom.xml file (see below).

However, when I run `mvn clean compile assembly:single`,

I get the following error: 
`Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (default-cli) on project hyuga: Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found. -> [Help 1]`

What am I missing?

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>dg2cep</id>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>br.pucrio.inf.lac.konoha.hyuga.core.Bootstrap</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <finalName>dg2cep</finalName>
            </configuration>
            <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>playback</id>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>br.pucrio.inf.lac.konoha.hyuga.others.csv.CSVPlayback</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <finalName>playback</finalName>
            </configuration>
            <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: First use an uptodate version of the maven-assembly-plugin cause this version is more than ancient... current version is 2.6 http://maven.apache.org/plugins/

Comment: @khmarbaise, no luck:
See output here:
``
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.6:single (default-cli) on project hyuga: Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.6:single (default-cli) on project hyuga: Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found.``

Comment: Ah..you are executing it like this: ` mvn ... assembly:single `? If so don't do this.. use it within the life cycle like ` mvn clean package` ....

Comment: thanks @khmarbaise, it worked. Can you post your comment as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah..you are executing it like this: `mvn ... assembly:single` ? If so don't do this.. use it within the life cycle like `mvn clean package` ....